# How to draw edges with Jung library?

Tags: java, graph, jung

I have an implementation of a Graph and I want to visualize it using JUNG. My problem is that when I add an edge, I visualize 2 edges, for example 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 with the same weight, but I just want to see 1 edge.

My code:

```
public void createGraph(HashMap<Integer, Vertice<Integer, Integer>> vertices, long[][] matriz) {

    if (vertices != null) {

        Graph<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Arista<Integer, Integer>> ig = new SparseMultigraph<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Arista<Integer, Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            ig.addVertex(vertices.get(i));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if(matriz[i][j] > 0){
                    Arista<Integer, Integer> a= new Arista(vertices.get(i), vertices.get(j), (int)matriz[i][j]);
                    ig.addEdge(a, vertices.get(i), vertices.get(j));
                }                   
            }
        }


        VisualizationImageServer<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Arista<Integer, Integer>> vs = new VisualizationImageServer<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Arista<Integer, Integer>>(
                new KKLayout<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Arista<Integer, Integer>>(ig), new Dimension(680, 340));
        vs.setBackground(Color.GRAY);


        Transformer<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Paint> vertexColor = new Transformer<Vertice<Integer, Integer>, Paint>() {
            @Override
            public Paint transform(Vertice<Integer, Integer> i) {
                return Color.GREEN;
            }
        };

        vs.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexColor);


        vs.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Vertice<Integer, Integer>>());
        vs.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);


        vs.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new Transformer<Arista<Integer, Integer>, String>() {
            public String transform(Arista<Integer, Integer> e) {
                return (e.toString());
            }
        });

        this.add(vs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is probably in that double for loop that creates edges. Does your `matriz` structure have redundant informations, e.g. is `matriz[i][j]  == matriz[j][i]`?

Comment: yes... matriz[i][j] == matriz[j][i]

Comment: But that´s why I am just iterating in the lower triangular matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You have an undirected graph, so you should be using an implementation of `UndirectedGraph`.  SparseMultigraph allows both directed and undirected edges, and the default edge directionality is 'directed'.

The class you want is probably [UndirectedSparseGraph](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/UndirectedSparseGraph.html).